# How publish my module's assets in Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii-modules

I have a module with two views, I need that each view have its own assets files, because of this I wrote a AssetBundle called DashboardAsset for my dashboard view, this is the code.

```
class DashboardAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath ='@asketchFront/assets/resources/';
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';

    public $js =
    [
        "js/src/dashboard.js"
    ];

    public $css =
    [
        "css/dashboard.css",
        'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css',
    ];

}
```

Then in my dashboard view I put the following code line:

```
DashboardAsset::register($this);
```

afertward when I want to see my page, the following error messages are displayed in the console

```
GET http://localhost/js/src/dashboard.js  localhost/:478
GET http://localhost/css/dashboard.css  localhost/:19
GET http://localhost/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css
```

Why this happens??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem removing the **basepath** and the **baseurl** attributes